# Can't append to PATH in ~./bashrc using $Home

Tags: command-line, home-directory, environment-variables, bashrc, paths

I just want to add a path in `~/.bashrc` as:

```bash
export PATH="$Home/gg/gamit/bin:$Home/gg/kf/bin:$Home/gg/com:$PATH"
```

But when I am using `echo $PATH` is showing it as:

```bash
/gg/gamit/bin:/gg/kf/bin:/gg/com:/home/sandypuja/bin:/home/sandypuja/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

But I need it to look like

```bash
/home/sandypuja/gg/gamit/bin:/home/sandypuja/gg/kf/bin:/home/sandypuja/gg/com:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

where `sandypuja` is my system name.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive: `$HOME` is a recognised variable - `$Home` is not

Comment: $Home will be an empty string indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell and environment variables are [case-sensitive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Case_sensitivity) (as [steeldriver says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191057/unable-to-add-path-in-bashrc#comment1992718_1191057)). `Home` is not the same variable as `HOME`. The `HOME` environment variable contains a path to your home directory. The `Home` variable typically does not exist; there is nothing special about the name `Home`.

When a variable is not defined, performing [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on it yields the empty string (as [vanadium alludes to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191057/unable-to-add-path-in-bashrc#comment1992721_1191057)), which is what you're seeing.

**Replacing `$Home` with `$HOME`** should fix the problem:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/gg/gamit/bin:$HOME/gg/kf/bin:$HOME/gg/com:$PATH"
```

---

Note that you should not typically set environment variables, *especially* `PATH`, in `~/.bashrc`, because:

1. That file is only sourced by `bash` shells, so they will be unavailable in a number of important contexts including graphical programs not started from `bash`.
2. That file is sourced by all interactive `bash` shells, so when you start one interactive bash shell from another, the child shell will have the path modified again. So the directory name will be prepended multiple times. The performance impact is negligible but it can be quite confusing when you're inspecting the variable's value.

If you want [to set or modify an environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) like `PATH` by editing a file that is sourced by shells, [you can use `~/.profile` rather than `~/.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/60221/22949).

(I say "*especially* `PATH`" because it is very common to include the old value of `PATH` in the new value, as you are doing, and when this is done in `~/.bashrc` it creates the annoyance described in #2 above.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, Thanks A lot